# When is the given ODE exact?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $$y'=\frac{cx-ay}{ex+by}.$$ Find the values of the constants
>   $a,b,c,e\in\mathbb {R}$ such that the DE is exact. Give one particular
>   solution and the equation of the tangent that passes thru some point $(x_0,y_0)$.

What I have tried:

Let $P(x,y)=\frac{cx-ay}{ex+by}$ and $Q(x,y)=-1.$ Then the DE is equivalent to $P(x,y)+Q(x,y)y'=0$. P and Q are continuously differentiable in some region $D\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ (as they are polynomials). So I don't need to worry too much about that.

Obviously $ex+by\neq0$ must hold 
and

$ \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$ $\iff$ $\frac{-a\cdot(ex-by)-(cx-ay)\cdot b}{(ex+by)^2}=0 \iff -a\cdot(ex-by)-(cx-ay)\cdot b=0 \iff -x(ae+bc)=0$.

Therefore, $ae\neq-bc$.

My answer: $a,b,c,e\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $ae\neq-bc$ and $ex+by\neq0$. Is this correct and complete so far? Then I should give one particular solution which makes me a bit confused. Then I probably need to solve the ODE in order to point out one particular solution, right?

Comment: Usually one would take $P=cx-ay$ and $Q=-(ex+by)$

Comment: Does it make any difference?

Comment: Yes. It does. Multiplication of both sides of equation by some function of x and y might make it easier or harder to integrate. Note also, that if your equation is exact, then solution is found by integrating P wrt x or Q wrt y. Then an arbitrary constant appears. Which you could set to 0 for a particular solution

Comment: I did that and got $½cx^2-ayx-½by^2=C$ is the implicit solution. But what next? Can I choose a=0, b=c=1?

Comment: I have checked your solution, and it's correct. No, you can't choose the values of the parameters, that's not what the problem is asking. They want you to choose one particular value for the integration constant $C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP has all the necessary background, but had some trouble applying it. In the end, they have gotten the correct solution on their own (in the comments at this point).

I hope the following might clear up some things. First, let us rewrite the equation in a more 'symmetric' form (it is very important, since what you tried at first would not do - the functions were too different):

$$(cx-ay)dx-(ex+by)dy=0$$

Or, introducing some functions:

$$P(x,y)dx+Q(x,y)dy=0$$

For the equation to be exact, the following should hold (as you correctly point out):

$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$$

Applying this:

$$-a=-e \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad e=a$$

Now we have:

$$P(x,y)=cx-ay \\ Q(x,y)=-ax-by$$

The reason there's a special cathegory of 'exact equations' is that they can be represented as a full differential of some function:

$$dU(x,y)=\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial U}{\partial y}dy=0$$

This also means the function itself is equal to a constant. This will be our implicit solution.

Since:

$$P=\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}$$

$$U=\int P dx=\frac{1}{2}cx^2-ayx+f(y)=C$$

Where $f(y)$ is any function of $y$. While $C$ is a constant in both $x$ and $y$.

On the other hand:

$$Q=\frac{\partial U}{\partial y}$$

$$U=\int Q dy=-ayx-\frac{1}{2}by^2+g(x)=C$$

Where $g(x)$ is any function of $x$.

Obviously both expressions need to be equal:

$$\frac{1}{2}cx^2-ayx+f(y)=-ayx-\frac{1}{2}by^2+g(x)$$

Which makes the implicit solution:

> $$U(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}cx^2-ayx-\frac{1}{2}by^2=C$$

Now the question asks for a particular solution (we can simply take $C=0$) and for the equation of the tangent (which I leave to the OP unless they have some trouble at this step).

Comment: Isn't the equation of the tangent $y=y'(x-x_0)+y_0$, where $y'=\frac{cx-ay}{ax+by}$?

Comment: @1likeMaths, only you need to take $y'(x_0,y_0)=\frac{cx_0-ay_0}{ax_0+by_0}$, but yes, I think so. Make sure to check yourself in any case, don't just trust strangers on the internet :)